# Display flex tailwind not working in react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

So i have component in react to be styled as this pic below and have to be responsive:
[image]

But when i implemented the code using tailwind and react instead of looking like the pic below, it becomes like this:
[image]

I am using flex justify-between to create it, and here is my try:

```
const CardCalculation = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-betwween">
      <div className="w-[120px] h-[100px] m-2 absolute bg-[#d9d9d9]">
        <p className="absolute text-2xl text-left text-[#e44]">N RCO 250gr</p>
        <p className="absolute  text-xl text-left text-[#b4b4b4]">12x5cm</p>
        <p className="absolute  text-xl text-left text-[#b4b4b4]">Rp. 82.000</p>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center  absolute gap-2.5 px-[84px] py-3 rounded-md border border-[#f7d716]">
        <div className="flex justify-start items-center flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 w-[104px] relative gap-4">
          <svg
            width={12}
            height={12}
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            className="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
          >
            <rect
              x={1}
              y={1}
              width={22}
              height={22}
              rx={11}
              stroke="#F7D716"
              stroke-width={2}
            />
            <g clip-path="url(#clip0_83_406)">
              <rect
                width="12.6316"
                height="12.6316"
                transform="translate(5.68457 5.6842)"
                fill="#F7D716"
              />
              <path
                d="M18.0226 7.74877C17.6318 7.35742 16.9972 7.35767 16.6058 7.74877L10.2292 14.1256L7.39513 11.2915C7.00378 10.9002 6.36942 10.9002 5.97808 11.2915C5.58673 11.6829 5.58673 12.3172 5.97808 12.7086L9.52058 16.2511C9.71612 16.4466 9.97254 16.5446 10.229 16.5446C10.4854 16.5446 10.7421 16.4469 10.9376 16.2511L18.0226 9.16579C18.414 8.77472 18.414 8.14009 18.0226 7.74877Z"
                fill="white"
              />
            </g>
            <defs>
              <clippath id="clip0_83_406">
                <rect
                  width="12.6316"
                  height="12.6316"
                  fill="white"
                  transform="translate(5.68457 5.6842)"
                />
              </clippath>
            </defs>
          </svg>
          <p className="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-lg text-left text-[#f7d716]">
            Edit
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center absolute mt-20 gap-2.5 px-[84px] py-3 rounded-md border border-[#e44]">
        <div className="flex justify-start items-center flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 w-[104px] relative gap-4">
          <svg
            width={24}
            height={24}
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            className="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
          >
            <rect
              x={1}
              y={1}
              width={22}
              height={22}
              rx={11}
              stroke="#EE4444"
              stroke-width={2}
            />
            <g clip-path="url(#clip0_83_388)">
              <path
                d="M18.0226 7.74877C17.6318 7.35742 16.9972 7.35767 16.6058 7.74877L10.2292 14.1256L7.39513 11.2915C7.00378 10.9002 6.36942 10.9002 5.97808 11.2915C5.58673 11.6829 5.58673 12.3172 5.97808 12.7086L9.52058 16.2511C9.71612 16.4466 9.97254 16.5446 10.229 16.5446C10.4854 16.5446 10.7421 16.4469 10.9376 16.2511L18.0226 9.16579C18.414 8.77472 18.414 8.14009 18.0226 7.74877Z"
                fill="#EE4444"
              />
            </g>
            <defs>
              <clippath id="clip0_83_388">
                <rect
                  width="12.6316"
                  height="12.6316"
                  fill="white"
                  transform="translate(5.68457 5.6842)"
                />
              </clippath>
            </defs>
          </svg>
          <p className="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-lg text-left text-[#e44]">
            Copy
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default CardCalculation;
```

Can someone pointing out which line i should improve or any help on this..., anyhelp to this will be very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code needed really fine tuning. The major one I see is every div is using `absolute` which places the elements on stack. Remove those absolute and try the below code.

##### Try the below code:

```
<div class="justify-betwween flex flex-row">
  <div class="m-2 h-[100px] w-2/12 bg-[#d9d9d9]"></div>
  <div class="flex w-8/12 flex-col items-start justify-center gap-2 p-4">
    <p class="text-left text-3xl text-[#e44]">N RCO 250gr</p>
    <p class="text-left text-2xl text-[#b4b4b4]">12x5cm</p>
    <p class="text-left text-2xl text-[#b4b4b4]">Rp. 82.000</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w-2/12 p-2">
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-2.5 rounded-md border border-[#f7d716] py-3">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-start md:gap-4">
        <svg width="{24}" height="{24}" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 flex-shrink-0 flex-grow-0" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
          <rect x="{1}" y="{1}" width="{22}" height="{22}" rx="{11}" stroke="#F7D716" stroke-width="{2}" />
          <g clip-path="url(#clip0_83_406)">
            <rect width="12.6316" height="12.6316" transform="translate(5.68457 5.6842)" fill="#F7D716" />
            <path d="M18.0226 7.74877C17.6318 7.35742 16.9972 7.35767 16.6058 7.74877L10.2292 14.1256L7.39513 11.2915C7.00378 10.9002 6.36942 10.9002 5.97808 11.2915C5.58673 11.6829 5.58673 12.3172 5.97808 12.7086L9.52058 16.2511C9.71612 16.4466 9.97254 16.5446 10.229 16.5446C10.4854 16.5446 10.7421 16.4469 10.9376 16.2511L18.0226 9.16579C18.414 8.77472 18.414 8.14009 18.0226 7.74877Z" fill="white" />
          </g>
          <defs>
            <clippath id="clip0_83_406">
              <rect width="12.6316" height="12.6316" fill="white" transform="translate(5.68457 5.6842)" />
            </clippath>
          </defs>
        </svg>
        <p class="text-left text-lg text-[#f7d716]">Edit</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-[20px] flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-2.5 rounded-md border border-[#e44] py-3">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-start md:gap-4">
        <svg width="{24}" height="{24}" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 flex-shrink-0 flex-grow-0" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
          <rect x="{1}" y="{1}" width="{22}" height="{22}" rx="{11}" stroke="#EE4444" stroke-width="{2}" />
          <g clip-path="url(#clip0_83_388)">
            <path d="M18.0226 7.74877C17.6318 7.35742 16.9972 7.35767 16.6058 7.74877L10.2292 14.1256L7.39513 11.2915C7.00378 10.9002 6.36942 10.9002 5.97808 11.2915C5.58673 11.6829 5.58673 12.3172 5.97808 12.7086L9.52058 16.2511C9.71612 16.4466 9.97254 16.5446 10.229 16.5446C10.4854 16.5446 10.7421 16.4469 10.9376 16.2511L18.0226 9.16579C18.414 8.77472 18.414 8.14009 18.0226 7.74877Z" fill="#EE4444" />
          </g>
          <defs>
            <clippath id="clip0_83_388">
              <rect width="12.6316" height="12.6316" fill="white" transform="translate(5.68457 5.6842)" />
            </clippath>
          </defs>
        </svg>
        <p class="text-left text-lg text-[#e44]">Copy</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Output in large device:

[image]

#### Output in small device:

[image]

#### [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/EAOMM0ZdPs)

Comment: pardon me, but is that already responsive to the screen..?

Comment: pardon me , you are providing the code which has static values of width and height and how can you expect it to be responsive ?

Comment: Instead mention question asking a particular layout and that being responsive, I could have possibly given you the responsive code. Instead of tuning the broken code .

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: Sorry for bothering u again, but i have try my own style but i have some issue on that... can you take a look on it..., here is the link i asked for..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75017205/responsive-media-react-tailwind

Comment: thanks a lot man..., hope you can help me on that last question..

Comment: @nabatiadmin i have provided the code for just small devices, give me sometime. I'll fix it for you, and make it responsive

Answer (score 0):

Your first div in the "justify-content" block is in position absolute, so the second fit to the left, you should remove the position 'absolute'

Answer (score 0):

First of `absolute` is messing the layout. Second is a little bit verbose and so it is easy to lose track of all the containers you need. There are also some margins that are not needed as the layout could be used to create the separations.

Here is a working snippet (because of *tailwind* warnings, I suggest you view it fullscreen). To view it clearly you can check this [tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/W5JosPCDCu) (beware if copying the code that *className* have been changed for *class* and self-enclosing elements are not supported).

```js
const CardCalculation = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-row justify-between gap-1">
      <div className="flex flex-row">
        {/* INFO: this is the grey box container */}
        <div className="w-[120px] h-[100px] m-2 bg-[#d9d9d9]" />
        {/* INFO: this is the paper info container */}
        <div className="flex flex-col items-start justify-center gap-1 p-2">
          <p className="text-2xl text-left text-[#e44]"> N RCO 250 gr </p>
          <p className="text-xl text-left text-[#b4b4b4]"> 12 x5cm </p>
          <p className="text-xl text-left text-[#b4b4b4]"> Rp.82.000 </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* INFO: finally this is the right-most container */}
      <div className="h-full flex flex-col justify-center gap-3">
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-2.5 px-[84px] py-3 rounded-md border border-[#f7d716]">
          <div className="flex justify-start items-center flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 w-[104px] relative gap-4">
            <svg
              width={12}
              height={12}
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              fill="none"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              className="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6"
              preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
            >
              <rect
                x={1}
                y={1}
                width={22}
                height={22}
                rx={11}
                stroke="#F7D716"
                strokeWidth={2}
              />
              <g clipPath="url(#clip0_83_406)">
                <rect
                  width="12.6316"
                  height="12.6316"
                  transform="translate(5.68457 5.6842)"
                  fill="#F7D716"
                />
                <path
                  d="M18.0226 7.74877C17.6318 7.35742 16.9972 7.35767 16.6058 7.74877L10.2292 14.1256L7.39513 11.2915C7.00378 10.9002 6.36942 10.9002 5.97808 11.2915C5.58673 11.6829 5.58673 12.3172 5.97808 12.7086L9.52058 16.2511C9.71612 16.4466 9.97254 16.5446 10.229 16.5446C10.4854 16.5446 10.7421 16.4469 10.9376 16.2511L18.0226 9.16579C18.414 8.77472 18.414 8.14009 18.0226 7.74877Z"
                  fill="white"
                />
              </g>
              <defs>
                <clippath id="clip0_83_406">
                  <rect
                    width="12.6316"
                    height="12.6316"
                    fill="white"
                    transform="translate(5.68457 5.6842)"
                  />
                </clippath>
              </defs>
            </svg>
            <p className="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-lg text-left text-[#f7d716]">
              Edit
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-2.5 px-[84px] py-3 rounded-md border border-[#e44]">
          <div className="flex justify-start items-center flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 w-[104px] relative gap-4">
            <svg
              width={24}
              height={24}
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              fill="none"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              className="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6"
              preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
            >
              <rect
                x={1}
                y={1}
                width={22}
                height={22}
                rx={11}
                stroke="#EE4444"
                strokeWidth={2}
              />
              <g clipPath="url(#clip0_83_388)">
                <path
                  d="M18.0226 7.74877C17.6318 7.35742 16.9972 7.35767 16.6058 7.74877L10.2292 14.1256L7.39513 11.2915C7.00378 10.9002 6.36942 10.9002 5.97808 11.2915C5.58673 11.6829 5.58673 12.3172 5.97808 12.7086L9.52058 16.2511C9.71612 16.4466 9.97254 16.5446 10.229 16.5446C10.4854 16.5446 10.7421 16.4469 10.9376 16.2511L18.0226 9.16579C18.414 8.77472 18.414 8.14009 18.0226 7.74877Z"
                  fill="#EE4444"
                />
              </g>
              <defs>
                <clippath id="clip0_83_388">
                  <rect
                    width="12.6316"
                    height="12.6316"
                    fill="white"
                    transform="translate(5.68457 5.6842)"
                  />
                </clippath>
              </defs>
            </svg>
            <p className="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-lg text-left text-[#e44]">
              Copy
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<CardCalculation />, rootElement);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

Comment: pardon me, but is that already responsive to the screen..?

Comment: flex usually does respond to changes in size adjusting accordingly, nevertheless there are some elements on your desing that have size constraints and won't change any further from a certain breakpoint. You can change the layout at that breakpoint or eliminate those constraints. Another option is use *flex-wrap*.