# Responsive Media React Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

So i have component that i try to make it responsive, but when it comes to media below md: it not working at all and i have some problem on turning the view into what i want
Here is the look on the web view:
[image]

and here is the problem :
[image]

is that posible to make the button into this when it comes to phone view?
[image]

Here is my try:

```
const CardCalculation = () => {
  return (
    

    <div className="ml-2">
  <div className="mx-auto lg:flex lg:items-center lg:justify-between">
    <h2 className="tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-xl">
      <div className="gap-2">
        <div className="w-[120px] h-[110px] absolute bg-[#d9d9d9] lg:mb-10"></div>
        <div className="text-xl ml-32 text-left text-[#e44]">
          Mie Goleng
        </div>
        <div className="ml-32 text-left text-[#b4b4b4]">Plant K103.</div>
        <div className="ml-32 text-left text-[#b4b4b4]">500.02 UOG.</div>
      </div>
    </h2>
    <div className="mt-4 flex lg:mt-0 lg:flex-shrink-0 md:mt-4 sm:mt-8">
      <div>
        <div className="rounded-md mb-2 shadow">
          <a
            href="#"
            className="inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-indigo-600 px-5 py-3 text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-indigo-700"
          >
            Get started
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="rounded-md shadow">
          <a
            href="#"
            className="inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-indigo-600 px-5 py-3 text-base font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-50"
          >
            Learn more
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  );
};
export default CardCalculation;
```

can someone explained to me why it not responsive to the screen and does it possible to turn the button into horizontal when it comes to phone view as below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Use the following code:

```
<div class="p-2">
  <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row md:justify-between">
    <div class="flex gap-4">
      <div name="grey window" class="h-[110px] w-[120px] bg-[#d9d9d9]"></div>
      <div name="text" class="pt-2 md:flex md:flex-col md:justify-evenly md:pt-4">
        <div class="text-xl text-[#e44] md:text-3xl">Mie Goleng</div>
        <div class="mt-2 text-[#b4b4b4] md:text-xl">Plant K103.</div>
        <div class="mt-2 text-[#b4b4b4] md:text-xl">500.02 UOG.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div name="Buttons">
      <div class="flex gap-4 md:flex-col p-4 md:p-0">
        <div class="rounded-md shadow">
          <a href="#" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-indigo-600 px-5 py-3 text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-indigo-700 md:text-xl"> Get started </a>
        </div>
        <div class="rounded-md shadow">
          <a href="#" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-indigo-50 px-5 py-3 text-base font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-400 hover:text-white md:text-xl"> Learn more </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Output on large devices:

[image]

#### Output on small devices:

[image]

[Tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/eE1XByKN1a)

Comment: Hey man can you take a look on my new edit and my question, at web view it will stack vertically, but on phones view i hope i can be transformed into horizontally align as i mentioned on the question.... @KrishnaAcharya

Comment: Kinldy wait for your feedback... @KrishnaAcharya

Comment: @18-15 yeah sure. Could you possibly send the layout , how you want these elements to be shown in different screens , so that i can layout them accordingly for different devices

Comment: only two layout as i mentioned in the question... when it on web view the button stacked vertically, but when it comes to phones view it become horizontaly side by side align... @Krishna Acharya

Comment: Thanks a lot man... @KrishnaAcharya.. kindly wait for your feedback..

Comment: There you go !! It is now responsive, Additionally I fixed the color of button at base and hover state, and added responsive text size in large and small devices. Hope it helps !

Comment: Yup i made some adjustment to your code, it works perfectly, can u tell me where the best web or course to learn tailwind... kinda hard for me to learn it all by myself and i can not keep depending on stackoverflow @KrishnaAcharya

Comment: Learn it from documentation, it's the best place, more over on pro tip i would give you is that, tailwind-css is mobile first design system, meaning try designing to your mobile first, and then add responsiveness to larger devices using md: lg: extra. Trust me this approach works very smooth. Hope it helps.